# Вопрос по поводу ООП

Tags: c++, ооп, unreal-engine-4, blueprint, unreal-engine

Что делать, если есть какая-либо логика, которая совпадает в разных классах. Например в оружии и в фонарике(при перезарядке и при замене батареи соответственно), унаследовать их от одного класса, в котором будет прописана логика перезарядки или же отдельно прописать логику для каждого из них?

Comment: Сделать общий перезаряжаемый предок и вынести в него.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"ООП - ответ на это" - не просто наследоваться, а сделать интерфейс, который включает в себя *только* функции зарядки, и уже этот интрефейс имплементировать во всех классах, где есть что то, что по сути является "зарядкой".